# How to have Access Token Facebook SDK 4.4.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to use Facebook SDK to get my photo's url, and display it. I log in with fb sdk, but each time I open my app, I must log out and log in again to have access token. Can I have acces token without log in fb? And can I have access token of my friend's page? Please help me.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ImageView image;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private AccessToken accessToken;
JSONObject jsObject = null;
public MyAsyncTask myAsy;
public String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            accessToken,
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    // Get images's url code


                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "photos{images}");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    // info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you can't get a user access token without first logging the user in. Access tokens have an expiry time and have to be renewed/re-issued from time to time.

2) If by "can I get an access token for a friend's page" mean if you can get an access token for a friend without said friend doing anything, then no, you can't. You need to have that friend login to your app just like every other user.